# Symfony2 Sessions > Store & Retrieve array/collection of items in session

Tags: php, session, symfony

I do not know if this is question worthy. I have read up on the documentation, but coming from and old PHP $_SESSION environment I am not sure how to implement. I have a quiz type application. At initiation of the quiz I want to get all the questions in the quiz and store them in the session. When retrieving the next question I want to check if the questions exist in the the session, if they do then I retrieve the next question. I have the following:

```
public function nextQuestionAction()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();

    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();

    if ($session->has('quiz_questions'))
    {
        $session->get('quiz_questions');
        // Get the next question from the session, 
        // based on the previous question's ID, $data['question_id'];
        // The questions are ordered by an order_index and not by id, but
        // I get the session index based on $data['question_id'] and then 
        // retrieve the next one in line based on the index, or something
        // along that line
        // If there is no next question, then the session must be unset
    }
    else
    {
        $session->create('quiz_questions');

        $quiz = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('CriticalReadingQuizBundle:Quiz')
        ->find($data['quiz_id']);

        $questions = $quiz->getQuestions();
        // Store questions in session in such a way that I can retrieve 
        //the next question when this function gets called again.
        //The questions are ordered by an order_index and not by id, but they can
        //be stored in the session in their order with some arbitrary index so that
        //the next in line can be retrieved based on the index of the previous.
    }

    ... // Rest of code returns the fetched question to the front-end.
    // If this is the first time that the function is called, the first question is returned.
    //If there are no questions left (previous fetch fetched the last question), return null.
}
```

If somebody could please assist me with the code on working with sessions in Symfony2 as it is the first time that I am working with them. I can post the Quiz and Question entities if they are required, but I do not think that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic Symfony2 session object example here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session

Comment: Thank your for your feedback. I have read this documentation. However, this only specifies how to set a single session property. I am looking for a solution that sets an entire session object, and even more extensively, setting an array/collection of objects within the session.