# Symfony2, print_r on collection of objects never completes

Tags: php, symfony

I am still new to Symfony2, and I am struggling my but off. I would actually like a proper answer to this question: [Symfony2 Sessions > Store & Retrieve array/collection of items in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545916/symfony2-sessions-store-retrieve-array-collection-of-items-in-session) , but in the meantime I have had to resort to some "dirty" PHP using $_SESSION. However, I seem to have run into a snag where my function never completes. I am pretty sure it is because the question entity has a many to one mapping with the Quiz entity (So a quiz has questions, and each question has a quiz, which has questions, etc, etc, bad loop), but I do not know how to fix this. My code looks as follows:

```
public function nextQuestionAction()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['questions']))
    {
        $quiz = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('CriticalReadingQuizBundle:Quiz')
            ->find($data['quiz_id']);

        $questions = $quiz->getQuestions();

        print_r($questions); die();

        $_SESSION['questions'] = $questions;
        $question = $questions[0];
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($_SESSION['questions'] as $key => $question)
        {
            if ($question['id'] == $data['question_id'])
            {
                if(isset($_SESSION['questions'][$key+1]))
                    $question = $_SESSION['questions'][$key+1];
                else
                {
                    unset($_SESSION['questions']);
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    return $this->createJsonResponse($question);
}
```

I put in the print_r($questions); die(); to see what I get in my questions, but no surprise, that doesn't completeI either. I know that am doing/missing something stupid, but I do not know what it is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r()` on this type of nested objects can crash so badly that not even an error is output. You can try `print_r($questions->toArray())`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, while your suggestion did not work (not your fault, my code looks a little different than what posted, for simplification), I did find a workaround that seems to work pretty well.